# Key_error при попытке вывести на печать ключ от словаря

Tags: python, словари

При запуске выводит на печать data в виде словаря, но при попытке вывести на печать print(data[0]) выскакивает ошибка key_error 0. Заблудился в трех соснах, помогите разобраться.

```
def request_book(api_method, params_dict):
    params_dict['nonce'] = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    params_urlencoded = urllib.parse.urlencode(params_dict)
    sign_bytes = get_signature(params_urlencoded)

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Key': PUBLIC_KEY,
        'Sign': base64.b64encode(sign_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    }

    response = requests.get(
        urllib.parse.urljoin(TRANSACTION_API_URL, api_method), headers=headers, data=params_urlencoded)

    try:
        response_json = response.json()
        if response_json['success'] == 0:
            print('Received error: {}'.format(response_json['error']))
        return response_json
    except Exception as ex:
        #print(response.json())
        return response_json



if __name__ == '__main__':
    data =request_book('/mapi/v2/depth/eurusd', {})
    print(data)
```

это словарь, который печатает print(data)

```
{'eurusd': {'asks': [[1.147, 2000],
                     [1.148271, 29190.8],
                     [1.148278, 77046.3],
                     [1.148285, 76735.2],
                     [1.148292, 3555.1],
                     [1.148293, 5870.9],
                     [1.148297, 64921.8],
                     [1.148299, 28708.8],
                     [1.148302, 98302.3],
                     [1.148306, 95492.2],
                     [1.148319, 22526.6],
                     [1.14832, 44616.7],
                     [1.148324, 19006.9],
                     [1.148328, 12004.8],
                     [1.148331, 39137.3],
                     [1.148357, 67219.1],
                     [1.148366, 39256],
                     [1.14837, 21136.3],
                     [1.148371, 73958.5],
                     [1.148376, 59804.2],
                     [1.148378, 77444.5],
                     [1.14838, 98295.3],
                     [1.148384, 61911.1],
                     [1.148385, 56456.3],
                     [1.148389, 525000],
                     [1.148391, 71467.2],
                     [1.148393, 19524.44],
                     [1.148396, 53030.1],
                     [1.148399, 3100000],
                     [1.148418, 82985.2],
                     [1.148423, 71374.6],
                     [1.148426, 53423.2],
                     [1.148431, 75243.6],
                     [1.148441, 70035.3],
                     [1.148447, 6333.9],
                     [1.148451, 10570.1],
                     [1.148467, 37142.2],
                     [1.148468, 73362.3],
                     [1.148479, 72116.4],
                     [1.1485, 23859.2],
                     [1.148503, 56489.9],
                     [1.148505, 197141],
                     [1.148506, 80696.4],
                     [1.148509, 60660.4],
                     [1.14851, 53577.8],
                     [1.148513, 97791.6],
                     [1.14853, 95873.1],
                     [1.148536, 834758.7],
                     [1.148538, 95015.3],
                     [1.148539, 500000],
                     [1.148542, 579760.5],
                     [1.148549, 51364.4],
                     [1.148552, 84633.3],
                     [1.148553, 93335.2],
                     [1.148592, 77570.1],
                     [1.148603, 25010.4],
                     [1.148611, 41763.8],
                     [1.14863, 2571314.8],
                     [1.148635, 20980.5],
                     [1.148654, 72429.9],
                     [1.148655, 19906.7],
                     [1.148677, 95119.1],
                     [1.14868, 31406.6],
                     [1.148689, 38952.2],
                     [1.148695, 775000],
                     [1.148696, 95030.3],
                     [1.148699, 96462.5],
                     [1.148701, 43143.4],
                     [1.148703, 82339.3],
                     [1.148707, 34728.6],
                     [1.148711, 1248447.6],
                     [1.148713, 82156.4],
                     [1.148719, 58296.6],
                     [1.148724, 71756.1],
                     [1.148747, 89336.6],
                     [1.148758, 500000],
                     [1.148759, 1000000],
                     [1.148761, 15171.9],
                     [1.148763, 40327.1],
                     [1.14877, 700000],
                     [1.148774, 49068.1],
                     [1.148779, 53401.1],
                     [1.148783, 56378.6],
                     [1.148784, 500000],
                     [1.148788, 3000000],
                     [1.148789, 500000],
                     [1.14879, 73391.2],
                     [1.148814, 80166.1],
                     [1.148828, 84488.9],
                     [1.148834, 89687.8],
                     [1.148836, 64280.1],
                     [1.148846, 28877.3],
                     [1.14885, 19243.4],
                     [1.148928, 1100000],
                     [1.148966, 2100000],
                     [1.1503, 1281.7],
                     [1.154, 1],
                     [1.15499, 190.43],
                     [1.155, 641],
                     [1.1555, 500],
                     [1.155999, 500],
                     [1.156, 500],
                     [1.1565, 500],
                     [1.157, 500],
                     [1.158, 500],
                     [1.1585, 58.91],
                     [1.1587, 500],
                     [1.159, 500],
                     [1.16, 2000],
                     [1.163, 500],
                     [1.179, 501],
                     [1.199, 24.3],
                     [1.2486, 20],
                     [1.295, 8.9]],
            'bids': [[1.139, 1040.2],
                     [1.138999, 17],
                     [1.136999, 29],
                     [1.135999, 29],
                     [1.135567, 58],
                     [1.135302, 34],
                     [1.135, 103],
                     [1.134999, 29],
                     [1.133999, 105],
                     [1.133852, 202.5],
                     [1.13346, 67],
                     [1.132999, 29],
                     [1.132002, 1840],
                     [1.132, 1816.8],
                     [1.131002, 2042.8],
                     [1.131, 5500],
                     [1.130999, 29],
                     [1.13046, 56],
                     [1.130099, 55],
                     [1.130067, 171],
                     [1.129999, 70],
                     [1.129499, 150],
                     [1.129388, 41],
                     [1.129199, 41],
                     [1.128999, 29],
                     [1.128599, 167],
                     [1.128499, 29],
                     [1.127999, 29],
                     [1.127499, 29],
                     [1.126999, 29],
                     [1.126499, 29],
                     [1.126, 500],
                     [1.125999, 29],
                     [1.125499, 160],
                     [1.125477, 14232.9],
                     [1.125468, 72377.1],
                     [1.125453, 4864.5],
                     [1.125449, 58544.5],
                     [1.125446, 59514.2],
                     [1.125442, 106831.3],
                     [1.125414, 1018073.3],
                     [1.125403, 18916.7],
                     [1.125391, 68484.8],
                     [1.125377, 78192.6],
                     [1.125372, 85260.7],
                     [1.125366, 40937],
                     [1.12535, 32716.2],
                     [1.125345, 63608.7],
                     [1.125332, 1500000],
                     [1.125328, 105679.6],
                     [1.125323, 1600000],
                     [1.125319, 97836.8],
                     [1.125312, 9999.1],
                     [1.125311, 46583.7],
                     [1.12531, 27764.5],
                     [1.125308, 109703.9],
                     [1.125304, 71011],
                     [1.125287, 33041.3],
                     [1.125286, 30204],
                     [1.125285, 36923.6],
                     [1.125283, 39013.9],
                     [1.125257, 94277.8],
                     [1.125252, 46075.4],
                     [1.125248, 28484.1],
                     [1.125246, 130701.4],
                     [1.125243, 62362.5],
                     [1.125241, 22003.2],
                     [1.12524, 11459.1],
                     [1.125234, 31652.7],
                     [1.125228, 75576.9],
                     [1.125218, 65327.8],
                     [1.125215, 62319],
                     [1.125213, 500000],
                     [1.125198, 54522.3],
                     [1.125197, 35725.8],
                     [1.125189, 31933.9],
                     [1.125184, 14032.8],
                     [1.12518, 80293],
                     [1.125179, 91764.9],
                     [1.125178, 72922],
                     [1.125165, 71045],
                     [1.12516, 56718],
                     [1.125153, 15103.8],
                     [1.12515, 62865.4],
                     [1.125149, 1000000],
                     [1.125143, 76709.3],
                     [1.125139, 15873.3],
                     [1.125136, 7555.5],
                     [1.125132, 83348.3],
                     [1.125131, 20278.2],
                     [1.125125, 1025000],
                     [1.125123, 47763.8],
                     [1.125119, 400000],
                     [1.125108, 52263.4],
                     [1.125104, 8184.7],
                     [1.125101, 98650],
                     [1.1251, 88001.6],
                     [1.125094, 123366.8],
                     [1.125089, 78371.4],
                     [1.125081, 62453.7],
                     [1.125079, 41388.8],
                     [1.12507, 843986],
                     [1.125067, 39877.4],
                     [1.125064, 48664.3],
                     [1.125059, 3000000],
                     [1.125055, 40666.4],
                     [1.12505, 53916.2],
                     [1.125041, 94640.6],
                     [1.125023, 84067.4],
                     [1.125021, 96556.7],
                     [1.12502, 18951.2],
                     [1.125013, 500000],
                     [1.125, 528],
                     [1.124999, 29],
                     [1.124994, 2100000],
                     [1.124987, 1025000],
                     [1.124985, 1275000],
                     [1.124983, 47775.8],
                     [1.12498, 88369.6],
                     [1.124948, 4385.7],
                     [1.124941, 1441.7],
                     [1.12492, 14880.7],
                     [1.12491, 500000],
                     [1.124907, 2100000],
                     [1.124903, 89363.7],
                     [1.124902, 80765.1],
                     [1.124897, 2000000],
                     [1.124893, 500000],
                     [1.123999, 29],
                     [1.12302, 95],
                     [1.122499, 131],
                     [1.121, 400],
                     [1.120875, 23],
                     [1.12014, 330],
                     [1.12, 187],
                     [1.11995, 34],
                     [1.11602, 95.5],
                     [1.116, 300],
                     [1.115, 1075],
                     [1.113852, 5000],
                     [1.11144, 142.8],
                     [1.11111, 232],
                     [1.111, 5300],
                     [1.11, 2818],
                     [1.106, 300],
                     [1.105, 96.3],
                     [1.103, 79.1],
                     [1.101, 333],
                     [1.091276, 57],
                     [1.091202, 70],
                     [1.081276, 114],
                     [1.071276, 114],
                     [1.071, 37],
                     [1.06767, 99],
                     [1.064567, 121],
                     [1.061276, 57],
                     [1.05599, 99],
                     [1.051276, 114],
                     [1.04899, 99],
                     [1.041276, 114],
                     [1.03499, 99],
                     [1.031276, 57],
                     [1.02499, 99],
                     [1.021276, 57],
                     [1.01499, 99],
                     [1.01, 414],
                     [1.0, 144],
                     [0.993367, 45],
                     [0.983367, 45],
                     [0.973367, 45],
                     [0.963367, 123],
                     [0.953367, 78],
                     [0.943367, 78],
                     [0.938367, 78],
                     [0.937367, 78],
                     [0.935367, 78],
                     [0.933367, 78],
                     [0.925367, 78],
                     [0.923367, 78],
                     [0.919367, 78],
                     [0.913367, 78],
                     [0.909367, 78],
                     [0.906367, 78],
                     [0.904367, 78],
                     [0.903367, 78],
                     [0.902367, 78]],
            'market_buy_price': 1.295,
            'market_sell_price': 0.902367}}
```

Comment: вы можете опубликовать функцию `get_signature` ?

Comment: Пытаюсь в нормальном виде дать код, но почему-то при постинге не идут отступы
DSX_URL = "https://dsx.uk/"
TRANSACTION_API_URL = urllib.parse.urljoin(DSX_URL, '')


def to_bytes(str):
    return str.encode('utf-8')


def get_signature(params_urlencoded):
    hmac_obj = hmac.new(to_bytes(SECRET_KEY), to_bytes(params_urlencoded), hashlib.sha512)
    return hmac_obj.digest()

Comment: Весь код должен быть в тексте вопроса, комментарии не предназначены для кода

Comment: Вы пишите, что `print(data[0]) выскакивает ошибка key_error 0.`, а что печатает `print(data)` ?

Comment: print(data) печатает словарь. При этом, если напечатать print(data['eurusd']), то никакой ошибки не выходит. Я могу и так работать, но уже дело принципа. Может я просто неправильно обращаюсь к ключу?

Comment: Вроде всё предельно ясно - в словаре нет элемента с ключом 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cловарём (или ассоциативным массивом) называется структура данных, позволяющая идентифицировать ее элементы **не по числовому индексу**, а по **произвольному**.

Индексом может быть любое неизменяемое значение, например:

```
data = {
    "some_key": 1,  # ключ строка, ок!
    1: ["1", "2"],  # ключ число, ок!
    (1,2,3): 1.0,   # ключ кортеж, ок! даже кортеж может быть ключом, ведь он неизменяемый
}
```

Однако, если список при добавлении элемента сам "создает" ему индекс, то словарь не добавляет своих индексов (ну... вообще добавляет, но это касается его внутреннего устройства). Он создает соответствие между **указанным ключом** и **значением** (для быстрого поиска этого значения).

Таким образом, при обращении `data[0]` в вашем случае словарь не находит этого *соответствия* (для ключа `0` его просто не существует), поэтому он ругается и выдает `KeyError`.